Where do I upload photos to the Android Emulator via Visual Studio 2022?
I am using Visual Studio 2022 (on Windows 11 Pro) and have created a MAUI Blazor project for Android. I am using the "Phone M-DPI 5.4in - API 30 (Android 11.0 - API 30)" emulator. The project builds and runs fine with no errors. I have a button to take a photo, which brings up the camera, which brings up a sample image...

I click the camera icon, and then the resultant checkmark to save the photo. I have also added a textfield which displays the location of the image...
/data/user/0/com.xxx.xxx/cache/65b2b9b31259497bb5536943cd976a64.jpg
I have searched my entire system for that image (beginning at "C:>") but can't find it anywhere. So where is that image stored? I want to add my own photos for testing purposes but don't know where to put them.
Notes...

Dragging-and-dropping from a folder to the emulator does not work. (I just get a "no" icon when trying.)
There is no icon on the emulator to open Google Mail, or I would try to email it to the emulator from my Gmail account.
I have even manually added a "Wall" photo via the Extended Controls but that never appears.


(See the red circles.)
Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

It is stored in .android/avd/<youremulator>/sdcard.img which is an img file, I don't think there is a way to get the image using the device explorer, have used Visual Studio like 5 years back so don't know if there is a Device explorer option (it is available in Android studio). If you have the device explorer you can visually see/explore the emulator files locate and extract/download the file using a simple right mouse click.
